# Storing and accessing objects in a class without a instance reference

Tags: java, static

I know in C# this is okay to do but what about in Java? I have tested it and it works but should it be avoided and if so, why?

```
public class A {
     public A() {
          B.set(this);
     }
}

public final class B {
     private static A a;

     public static void set(A a) {
          this.a = a;
     }

     public static A get() {
          return a;
     }

     private B() {
     }
}
```

Comment: Unclear is: static access should be avoided, or static classes at all

Comment: In Java and C# bot it is possible, in both is a bad pattern

Answer (score 0):

In Java this

```
private static A a;
```

is called an Class field, it has the same value, or in this case points to the same object in every instance of this class. Also it can be accessed without created instance of the class, in this case B.get(). You can change this

```
public static void set(A a) {
     this.a = a;
}

public static A get() {
     return a;
}
```

to this

```
public static void set(A a) {
     B.a = a;
}

public static A get() {
     return B.a;
}
```